# Pegar dados via POST

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Olá, preciso de ajuda para dar continuidade a um projeto, acredito que para o pessoal que já tem um conhecimento avançado é algo bem simples, mas como sou leigo é bem complexo.

Tenho uma página index onde o usuário vai digitar um PIN, pego esse PIN com ajax e envio para uma outra página SALVAR.PHP e nessa página faço a consulta ao banco retornando verdadeiro ou falso, porém está me retornando apenas o valor false/'nao encontrei nada', tenho em mente que digitei algo errado ou deixei de digitar e a variável contendo o PIN está indo para a análise vazia, coloquei a IMG do código no topico.

Alguém pode me ajudar?? Desde já agradeço, valeu.!

[image: Código fonte]

Comment: Quando colocar código na pergunta prefira texto ao invés de imagem. Muitos usuários acessam a página com celular e a imagem do código dificulta a leitura. Para usuários desktop a mudança de abas pode ser um incômodo. Também para responder a pegunta dificulta, pois ao invés de copiar e cola o código já existente teria que escreve-lo novamente.

Comment: Não, manjo muito de jquery, mas deve ser esse return false ali... Segue a dica do amigo acima e edite sua questão, colocando o código, não imagens. Considere visitar a [help]

Comment: Na linha onde está `data : {texto : 'texto'},` não deveria ser `data : {texto : $('#texto').val()},`